# how to save installs on linux usb

Tags: linux, usb, linux-mint

I'm a new person at Linux and am running Linux mint 15 cinnamon from an 8GB sandisk pendrive. I cannot dualboot it with windows until my friend (who is a genius at computers) backs up my windows (apparently). The thing is, I cannot save what I have done on it. for example, if I install drpython on my Linux and switch off my laptop, the next time I switch it on, it's all gone. 
can anyone tell me how I can save what I have done?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's two options here. You can re-burn the ISO onto the flash and setup a persistence file (I use `unetbootin`, but there are others). That will let you save some files on the flash. You are limited in how much space you have to do this though (4G last time I tried). And I'm not sure how this will behave when installing programs.

Your other alternative is to customize your distro. This is the most flexible option but is no simple thing to do. It is generally a well documented process though. There should be instructions for your distro out there.

You may, however, be able to bypass all of this. Linux can back up a Windows install. `fsarchiver` can archive NTFS partitions. You might want to back up the master boot record and partition table as well.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/home/mbr.dat bs=512 count=1
```